# Views - currently logged in user problem

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, views

There's a taxonomy list labeled `games-list` that's used in both the content type named `game` and user field `subscribed`. Each `game` has exactly one of the terms from `games-list` selected, but a user can select an unlimited amount of items within `subscribed`.

To be clear, both the user field `subscribed` and the content type field `game` are a term reference field that's linked to `games-list`.

My goal is to create a view that shows a list of content from `game` that is unique to each user, and that only shows the values of `game` that has been selected by the user from `subscribed`.

Whenever I try to filter by "currently logged in user," it only shows content that was authored by that user. Specifically, how do I configure the view to show only content that the user wants, regardless of who authored that content?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out.

The key was to create a "user" view from the beginning, and not a "content" view. Then, the view provided me with all the necessary relationships/filters that I could use. I got this idea from [Views - Filtering nodes by current user profile field](http://drupal.org/node/1111722).